# Foundation error functionality

Tags: jquery, asp.net, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use the '.error' class.
Every time I load the page it is OK. I enter some text in the field and press click submit and it just highlights the field with the error class.

I am using asp.net webforms (is this the problem)

```
$(function () {
  $('#main_btn_Submit').click(function (e) {
    if ($('#main_txt_name').val("")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#main_txt_name').addClass('error');
    }        
  });
});
```

Am I missing it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the value here `$('#main_txt_name').val("")` rather than checking to see if it is empty.

What you need is

```
if(!$('#main_txt_name').val())
```

Something like this:

```
$('#main_btn_Submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //do you really need this? It prevents the form from submitting, you might have to manually submit it later. 
    if(!$('#main_txt_name').val())
        $('#main_txt_name').addClass('error');
    }        
});
```

Comment: It just goes to the next page and does not seem to work. As I have a response.redirect on the submit.

Comment: You need to handle the code properly - put the response redirect in an else block